# Grouping rows by common date

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I have to following table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebets_odds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opponent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),
  KEY `opponent_id` (`opponent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `ebets_odds` (`id`, `datetime`, `match_id`, `opponent_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, '2013-09-04 23:09:39', 1, 1, 1.2),
(2, '2013-09-04 23:09:39', 1, 2, 1.8),
(3, '2013-09-05 11:54:10', 1, 1, 1.1),
(4, '2013-09-05 11:54:10', 1, 2, 1.9);
```

And I'd like to get the following SQL result :

```
2013-09-04 23:09:39 | 1.2 | 1.8
2013-09-05 11:54:10 | 1.1 | 1.9
```

So I would like to group by entries by datetime.
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT ODDS_1.datetime, ODDS_1.value AS odds_1, ODDS_2.value AS odds_2 
FROM ebets_odds ODDS_1, ebets_odds ODDS_2 
WHERE ODDS_1.match_id = 1 AND ODDS_2.match_id = 1 
GROUP BY ODDS_1.datetime
```

Comment: are you sure it's not working? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50cfb/1

Comment: What should happen if there are more than two entries with the same datetime? Or only one?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like pivot table? What if there are two records for one date and three - for another?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. with a simple loop in PHP, say). Besides, the use of GROUP BY in the absence of any aggregating functions is inappropriate.

Comment: there can't be three records for a given date, those values are added by form, with only 2 fields (odds 1 and odds 2) and I registered the registration date with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivoting query.  You seem to want information about the two opponents in different columns.  You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.datetime,
      max(case when opponent_id = 1 then o.value end) AS odds_1,
      max(case when opponent_id = 2 then o.value end) AS odds_2 
FROM ebets_odds o
WHERE match_id = 1
GROUP BY o.datetime;
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, except the values are really strange. look the output :Array
(
    [0] => Odds Object
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-09-04 23:09:39
            [odds_1] => 1.2000000476837158
            [odds_2] => 1.7999999523162842
        )

    [1] => Odds Object
        (
            [datetime] => 2013-09-05 11:54:10
            [odds_1] => 1.100000023841858
            [odds_2] => 1.899999976158142
        )

)

Comment: @VaN . . . The extra decimal points are an artifact of using `float` instead of a fixed length decimal representation, like `decimal(10, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

For some use cases this can be solved using the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function: it returns the values from a column as a comma-separated list. If commas don't work for you, you can pick a different separator. The list must then be processed in the application.

```
SELECT ODDS_1.datetime, GROUP_CONCAT(ODDS_1.value)
FROM ebets_odds ODDS_1
WHERE ODDS_1.match_id = 1
GROUP BY ODDS_1.datetime
```

Output:

```
2013-09-04 23:09:39 | 1.2,1.8
2013-09-05 11:54:10 | 1.1,1.9
```

Comment: ...must then be processed in the application, which rather negates the point.